# JavaFX ObservableList with extractor update event not firing when it should

Tags: java, javafx, properties, observable, observablelist

A little background:

Before I had a problem where I had `ObservableList` with extractor, but the properties that extractor was listening to were updated from **NOT** JavaFX thread. The solution I came up with was to create "UI equivalent" classes that would copy values of original class, just update their properties on JavaFX thread. For example, if we have a `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    private final BooleanProperty adult;

    public Person(boolean adult) {
        this.adult = new SimpleBooleanProperty(adult);

        // Randomize "adult" value every 5 seconds
        ListViewExtractorTest.scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            this.adult.set(Math.random() > 0.5);
            System.out.println("Updating adult: " + this);
        }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Getters setters
}
```

UI equivalent class would be:

```
public class PersonUI {

    private final Person person;
    private final BooleanProperty adult;

    public PersonUI(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
        adult = new SimpleBooleanProperty(person.isAdult());
        person.adultProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> this.adult.set(newValue));
        });
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

I did the same with `ObservableList` - created a method that would add a `ListChangeListener` to source list and whenever source list gets updated it would update destination list with UI equivalent classes on JavaFX thread:

```
public static <T, R> ObservableList<R> bindListContentPlatformRunLater(ObservableList<T> srcList, Function<T, R> function, ObservableList<R> dstList) {
    for (T item : srcList) {
        dstList.add(function.apply(item));
    }
    // Maybe should wrap the whole while loop in Platform.runLater()
    // Less runnables, but big changes might hang up the UI.
    srcList.addListener((ListChangeListener<? super T>) change -> {
        while (change.next()) {
            int from = change.getFrom();
            int to = change.getTo();
            if (change.wasPermutated()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> dstList.subList(from, to).clear());
                List<? extends T> addItems = change.getList().subList(from, to);
                for (int i = 0; i < addItems.size(); i++) {
                    final int index = i;
                    T addItem = addItems.get(i);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> dstList.add(from + index, function.apply(addItem)));
                }
            } else {
                if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    int removedSize = change.getRemovedSize();
                    Platform.runLater(() -> dstList.subList(from, from + removedSize).clear());
                }

                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    List<? extends T> addedSubList = change.getAddedSubList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < addedSubList.size(); i++) {
                        final int index = i;
                        T item = addedSubList.get(i);
                        Platform.runLater(() -> dstList.add(from + index, function.apply(item)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return dstList;
}
```

so now if I have `ObservableList<Person>` that is updated and has its item properties updated **NOT** on JavaFX thread, I can get a list that I can display in JavaFX easily:

```
ObservableList<PersonUI> secondList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(personUI -> new Observable[]{personUI.adultProperty()});
UIClassUtil.bindListContentPlatformRunLater(originalList, PersonUI::new, secondList);
```

so now the problem:

My expectation is that when `secondList` is displayed in `ListView<PersonUI>` it would update whenever `Person#adultProperty` values changes, but the expected behavior lasts only for a few seconds, after that the ListView stops updating and that happens because secondList "update" event stops firing. My guess is that `PersonUI#adultProperty` gets garbage collected after few seconds because it's not used anywhere else except in extractor??

To reproduce the issue I'm randomly changing the value of `Person#adultProperty` every few seconds. Full code without `Person` and `PersonUI` classes:

```
public final class ListViewExtractorTest extends Application {

    private static final ObservableList<Person> originalList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    static {
        for ( int a = 0; a < 5; a++ ) {
            originalList.add(new Person(Math.random() > 0.5));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<PersonUI> secondList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(personUI -> new Observable[]{personUI.adultProperty()});
        UIClassUtil.bindListContentPlatformRunLater(originalList, PersonUI::new, secondList);

        secondList.addListener((ListChangeListener<? super PersonUI>) change -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("List updated!");
                }
            }
        });
        ListView<PersonUI> listViewPerson = new ListView<>(secondList);
        ListView<PersonUI> listViewForceRefresh = new ListView<>(secondList);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(5, listViewPerson, listViewForceRefresh)));
        stage.setTitle("Hello");
        stage.show();

        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            Platform.runLater(listViewForceRefresh::refresh);
        }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

So I have two `ListView`: one on the left that should get updated whenever `Person#adultProperty` value changes and one on the right that I force refresh every 100ms. At first the lists are synced, but after a few seconds only the right list displays the correct values and left list gets stuck on same values and "List updated" of `ListChangeListener` gets printed only for the same first few seconds. So that means "update" event of the list is fired only for the same first few seconds.

However as soon as I start working with `PersonUI#adultProperty`(print it in console every few seconds using another thread) it starts behaving in expected behavior, so my guess is that it gets garbage collected if not used.

Any idea how could I make these properties of UI classes work as long as UI class itself is alive or somehow else achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: @moneydhaze I'm not using boolean binding?

Comment: There is a huge problem with your `ListChangeListener`: You retrieve the changes made on the javafx application thread. However on the thread where the change is triggered you may already have called `Change.next()`. Furthermore any modifications to the list from the non-application thread may not be visible to the application thread, java can use different copies of a object for multiple threads (as long as changes are not synchronized or done to a `volatile` field)...

Comment: @fabian I updated the code according to your comment, think it should be okay now? Not sure about the second part of your comment though.

Comment: too early for me to solve - but a) don't call it TransformationList if it isn't , b) don't use refresh ever .. why don't you implement a true TransformationList as suggested in your earlier question? it's plain easy and should be working without pain ..

Comment: @kleopatra a) updated, b) I'm using refresh just to show the problem? I'm not implementing the transformation list mainly because I want to use UI equivalent classes(so I don't have to add `Platform.runLater()` in listeners that modify UI, instead just use UI equivalent classes).

Comment: you have two moving bullets (the ui class and the shadow list) that's more complexity than a singe (real) Transformationlist (plus the latter has support methods to easily fire the required notifications)

Comment: @kleopatra I'll try to implement TransformationList to help performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix to prevent property from being garbage collected too early was to update listener in PersonUI constructor from:

```
person.adultProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> this.adult.set(newValue));
});
```

to:

```
person.adultProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    this.adult.get()
    Platform.runLater(() -> this.adult.set(newValue));
});
```